# Stop converting duplicate answers to comments

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, answers, comments

In case you didn't know, whenever you post the **exact same** answer as was already posted, it gets converted to a comment.

I had no idea before I posted a crack on a cops-and-robbers post that someone had posted 5s before.

I didn't know what happened before someone asked me why I commented on the question. I was confused for a bit until I figured it out.

While this may make sense for a Q&A site, it doesn't make sense for PPCG. 99% of the time, 2 people had the same idea at the same time.

### Here's what I'm proposing:

When you post a duplicate answer, this message appears:

> Your answer is an exact duplicate of [another answer](http://localhost/dup/answer/target). Please edit your answer if you would like to post it.

If this gets enough votes, I will post this to mother meta.

Comment: [Relevant.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10808/definite-policy-about-duplicate-answers)

Comment: Do we really want answers that are *exact* duplicates?  In the case of cracks there should only ever be one crack.  In the case of other answers I see no point in having two of the same answer.  I think this behavior makes just as much sense for a QA site as it does PPCG.

Comment: @programmer5000 This is something I agree with.  Silently converting to comments doesn't seem like a good idea.  However I don't see why this is the way it is for *any* site.  I don't think this is site specific.  Perhaps you should bring it up with the mother meta.

Comment: I, for one, agree.

Comment: I fell it's usually hard for program to decide what's `exact duplicate`. Maybe some explaining expression that don't effect at all.

Answer (score 1):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

This now provides a warning when posting a duplicate rather than automatically taking action on behalf of the user without properly making it clear to them.